# How to config cookie-only sessions in pylons?

Tags: pylons, session-cookies

I want to use cookie-only sessions in pylons. I have found some documents for this problem, but unfortunately, they said a lot, but where and how to config it.

http://pylonshq.com/docs/en/0.9.7/sessions/

http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/beaker/Cookie-Only+Sessions

I'm new to pylons, and I don't know how to config. Somebody can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found it in `development.ini`